# Is there a random variable $X$ with positive support such that the ratio of the two smallest realizations of an iid sample goes to one?

Tags: probability, distributions, order-statistics, extreme-value

Imagine I have given a random variable $X$ with supp$(X)=(0,\infty)$ and $\mathbb P(X \in (0,a))>0$ for any fixed $a>0$

Now  given an iid sample $X_1,...,X_n$ - is it possible that

$$X^{(2)}/X^{(1)}\xrightarrow{\mathbb P}1$$ for $n \to \infty$, where $X^{(i)}$ describes the $i$-th smallest element?

Comment: I'm not sure what your next-to-last paragraph means.   If you don't assume any distribution for $X$, you can't make any statements about the limit of the ratio unless those statements are true for all distributions - which this one evidently is not.    When you ask "Is there a random variable $X$...", what that actually means is "Is there a distribution such that the ratio of the smallest and second smallest realization of an iid sample drawn from the distribution goes to 1?"

Comment: @jbowman: Well yes I would like to know if it is not true for all distributions...or to say it another way:  can you name me a distribution of $X$ s.t. the ratio converge in probability to 1(or qn arbitrary fixed number)

Comment: I guess that would require a continuous density, zero at zero.

Comment: I lost the thread of your argument at "the probability that all ..., " because the probability that $X^{(1)}$ and $X^{(k)}$ are in the same random subsample of size $n/2$ is $2\binom{n/2}{2}/\binom{n}{2}\approx 1/2,$ not $(1/2)^k.$

Comment: I mean the probability that all $X^{(1)},...X^{(k)}$ are in the subsample.... if the sample is drawn independently then if I randomly divide the sample into two samples it can be considered to be binomial with p=1/2 (for $n$ to infinity and $k$ fixed)

Comment: Okay, that's clear.  What isn't clear is how it pertains to the original question.  Somehow (the mechanism remains obscure) you are removing the (strong) dependence between $X^{(1)}$ and $X^{(2)}$ and replacing it by the independent variables $X^{(1)}$ and $Y^{(1)}.$ I cannot see how this is correct or relevant to the answer.

Answer (score 6):

**Yes, there are such distributions** where the ratio of the second-smallest to smallest values approaches unity in probability as the sample size grows large.  They have to behave "essentially" like distributions with strictly positive support in the sense of approaching zero probability very, very rapidly at the origin.  See the first figure below for an illustration.

(I rely here on the correct intuition that when the distribution has a strictly positive minimum, eventually the two smallest values in large samples will both be  close to that minimum with high probability, whence their ratio approaches unity.  This intuition won't work when the minimum is zero.)

---

For convenience, let's work with independent and identically distributed random variables $X_i$ with continuous distributions.  This means they have a common density $f$ and $F(x)=F(0)+\int_0^x f(t)\mathrm{d}t$ is their common distribution function.

The question concerns the smallest two among the first $n$ of these variables, $X\lt Y,$ where $n$ will grow arbitrarily large.  The joint distribution of the two smallest values among them has density

$$f_{n;2}(x,y) = n(n-1)f(x)f(y)\left(1-F(y)\right)^{n-2}$$

for all $0\le x\le y.$  Introducing a variable $u$ defined by

$$x = uy$$

to represent the ratio $x/y\le 1,$ changing variables from $(x,y)$ to $(u,y),$ integrating from $u=0$ to $u=r$ (which can be expressed in terms of $F$), and integrating over all possible values of $y$  will give us the distribution function of the ratio $U=X/Y$ as

> $$\Pr(U \le r) = n(n-1)\int_0^\infty f(y)F(ry)(1-F(y))^{n-2}\,\mathrm{d}y$$ for $0 \le r \le 1.$

This expression will be the object of our analysis.

---

**In some cases the distribution of $U$ is easy to evaluate**.  Although this next section is a diversion, it reveals a thought process that leads to an answer.

Take, for instance, $$F_p(y) = y^p$$ for $0\le y\le 1$ where $p\gt 0.$  I obtain an answer that does not vary with $n$ at all: for possible ratios $0\le r \le 1,$

$$\Pr(U \le r) = r^p.\tag{1}$$

This indicates that any distribution $F$ that behaves like $F(y)\approx y^p$ near the origin will yield something like this power distribution for the ratio; in particular, it will not converge to $1$ in probability.

---

As $p$ grows large, $(1)$ does converge to the constant value $1$ in probability.  In other words, although we have not discovered any distributions where the ratio $U$ approaches $1$, we do have a family of distributions where this ratio can be made as close to $1$ as we might like by choosing a suitable member of the family (that is, by picking the power $p$ to be sufficiently large).  We might therefore consider distributions where, at the origin, $F$ is flatter than any polynomial.  The classic, and one of the simplest, such functions is

$$F(x) = \exp\left(1 - \frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$

for $0 \le x \le 1.$

Obviously its support extends down to $0,$ because the exponential is never zero.  $F$ is infinitely differentiable at $0$ but all derivatives are zero there.

[image: Graph of F]

In this case the integral for $\Pr(U\le r)$ still can be evaluated.  It is simpler to express the result in terms of $s \ge 1,$ where $$1/s^2 = r,$$ as

$$\Pr(U \le r) = \Pr(U \le 1/s^2) = \frac{e^{1-s}n!}{(1+s)^{(n-1)}}= s\,e^{1-s}\frac{1^{(n)}}{s^{(n)}}\tag{2}$$

where

$$s^{(n)} = s(1+s)(2+s)\cdots(n-1+s)$$

is the Pochhammer function.  Here are plots of this probability (as a function of $s$) for $n=2, 2^2, 2^{2^2}, 2^{2^3},$ and $2^{2^4}.$  The graphs drop towards a level of zero as $n$ increases:

[image: Figure 2]

It is easy to show that for all $z = s-1 \gt 0,$

$$\frac{1^{(n)}}{s^{(n)}} = \frac{1^{(n)}}{(1+z)^{(n)}} = \frac{1}{1+z}\frac{2}{2+z}\frac{3}{3+z}\cdots\frac{n}{n+z} \to 0$$

as $n$ grows large.  (Examine the MacLaurin series of its logarithm.)  Thus, for all $s=1+z \gt 1,$ $(2)$ goes to $0,$ demonstrating the ratio $U$ approaches the constant $1$ in probability.

Comment: Thank you already a lot - your solution is not trivial to me so I might need an hour to fully understand it; But may I ask what you mean with: (I rely here on the correct intuition that when the distribution has a strictly positive minimum, eventually the two smallest values in large samples will both be close to that minimum with high probability, whence their ratio approaches unity. This intuition won't work when the minimum is zero.) ? Do you mean that the random varialbe $X$ is lower bounded by some constant $c>0$?

Comment: Yes.  Specifically, there is a positive $c\gt 0$ such that $\Pr(X\lt c)=0.$

Comment: Yes it contradicts your assumption: I am pointing out that when $X$ has a positive minimum, the limiting ratio intuitively is $1.$  The idea is that we can emulate such an $X$ by making the probability go to zero extremely quickly at the origin.  The second part of my post, as stated, is just motivation for the counterexample to your conclusion, which is analyzed and illustrated in the last part.

Comment: Instead, I would like to invite you to follow my example and point out, if you can, where it errs.  I have carried it out rigorously but, as always, it's possible to make computational mistakes.  You might also find it congenial to analyze the *differences* between the *largest* two values in a sample: this is equivalent to your question when you consider $-\log(X_i)$ rather than the $X_i$ themselves.  A well-known distribution for which those differences converge to zero is the standard Normal distribution.

Comment: Nice! I came to the same result using the standard Fréchet distribution. With this choice we have $F(ry) = F(y)^{1/r}$ and using a change of variable $z:= F(y)$, the probability  $\text{Pr}(U \leqslant r)$ takes a simple form involving the Beta function, and a again the divergent infinite product gives the convergence in probability. We have the same flat behaviour near $0$.

Comment: @Yves Can you maybe guide me through the calculations you made? Something handwritten etc. will be totally fine; Then it seems like it is really possible; I am still wondering why my proof sketch is wrong though...

Comment: I only suggested a variant in the nice answer of whuber. By choosing the standard Fréchet $F(y) = \exp\{-1/y\}$ for $y >0$ the computation is quite simple.